# Pass a list of objects to a web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have a DataObjects class that contains a UserEmail object that contains an int (EmailID) and a string (EmailAddress).

Within a C# .net application, if I want to display a list of email addresses - I create and populate a list of UserEmail objects.

```
List<DataObjects.UserEmails> myUserEmailsList = new List<DataObjects.UserEmails>();
```

And use it as a datasource for whatever control I happen to be using.

I need to pass that list to a web service. I can't see how to do this. If the other party writes a web service with a method that takes a list as a parameter - fine, I can call the web service and pass my list. But how will they be able to extract the data from the list - without having access to the classes that created the objects in the list?

Is there a way of looping through a list of objects without knowing what the data structure of the object is?

Comment: Are you using SOAP or REST protocol for your web service?

Comment: The web service I am going to consume is to be REST I am told.

Answer (score 1):

When you are consuming their web service, you have to conform to their data structures.  You take your UserEmail object data, and would convert it to the object their service is expecting.

If you're using a service where it's just needing the data as get or post data, you'll have to use whatever keys they are requiring.  So they might take the email address using a key of "email" instead of your property name of "EmailAddress"

Comment: So if they have an object called EmailList with properties of EmailIdentifier and Email - I create a duplicate of my UserEmail object but called EmailList with 'their' properties of EmailIdentifier and Email instead of my properties of EmailID and EmailAddress?

Comment: I depends on the type of web service you are accessing.  Can you add some more information about the service you are going to consume to your question?

Comment: I don't know yet ... I guess I'll have to come back when I get given the info if I can't work out what is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
here a sample to pass list object to your webservice

    <%@WebService Language="c#" class="CustomObjectArrayWS"%>
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class CustomObjectArrayWS
{
        [WebMethodAttribute]
        [XmlInclude(typeof(Address))]
        public ArrayList GetAddresses ()
    {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        Address addr1 = new Address("John Smith", "New York",12345);
        Address addr2 = new Address("John Stalk", "San Fransisco", 12345);

            al.Add(addr1);
            al.Add(addr2);

            return al;
    }
} 
// Custom class to be added to the collection to be passed in //and out of the service
public class Address
{
    public string name;
    public string city;
    public int zip;     
    // Default ctor needed by XmlSerializer
    public Address()
    {
    }
    public Address(string _name, string _city, int _zip  )
    { 
                    this.name = _name;
                    this.city = _city;
                     this.zip = _zip;
           }
       }
```

see http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/XML-Webservice-FAQ-Pass-Array-Of-Custom-Objects

Comment: Thanks for your help - I can't pretend I fully get it - I'll give it a try and see if I can figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Ahh, the penny drops. Get it now. Thanks again.